# Fireworks en español

Tags: traducción, diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos

Me interesa saber en que forma puedo traducir esta palabra porque sé que está "Cohete" muy formal además de "Pirotecnia" y "Fuegos artificiales" que son demasiado técnicas. Estoy interesado en saber todas las formas posibles para decirlo en español, las formas que usa la gente común y corriente, no lo que dicte la norma oficial.

Comment: Suelo escuchar `cohete`

Answer (score 14):

Aquí, en España, usamos "Fuegos artificiales", sin que suene especialmente técnico. En tono coloquial, si está claro el contexto, tambien se dice a veces "los fuegos":

- ¡Vamos a ver los fuegos!
- ¡Vamos a ver los fuegos artificiales!

La palabra "pirotecnia" y derivados no se usa en el habla coloquial.

Answer (score 6):

Añado esta referencia de acuerdo con lo indicado en [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674). Edita libremente para incluir la versión de tu país o región.

---

### Argentina

- Fuegos artificiales

A los que explotan sin lluvia de luces se les llama "petardos".

### Chile

- Fuegos artificiales

Al evento se le llama "espectáculo de pirotecnia".

### Colombia

- Juegos pirotécnicos (organizados por el estado o alguna entidad y operados por profesionales)
- Pólvora (Quemar pólvora = Juegos/Fuegos artificiales usados por las personas del común, casi siempre de manera ilegal por encontrarse prohibidos en casi todo el país)

### Cuba

- Fuegos artificiales

### España

- Fuegos artificiales

### México

- Cuetes, Cuetones O "Castillos", tambien Fuegos Artificiales

Comment: Aquí en Chile, se dice *fuegos artificiales*, y al referirse al espectáculo donde los tiran, *espectáculo de pirotecnia*.

Comment: En Colombia decimos «juegos pirotécnicos» o simplemente «pirotécnicos». En [Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirotecnia) aparecen otras opciones como «fuegos artificiales» y «fuegos de artificio».

Comment: Según la RAE [cuete](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BbKTGhZ) en México es **ebrio**. Creo que en este caso es una mala pronunciación de **cohete**.

Comment: En Chile actualmente no se usan palabras específicas como "cuetes", "viejas", "petardos", "estrellitas", "bengalas" o "bombas" porque desde el año 2000 hay una ley estricta que los prohibe. Por lo tanto solo se ve fuegos artificiales desde lejos y las nuevas generaciones no conocen algo distinto a los "espectáculos pirotécnicos".

Comment: @DGaleano gracias por el apunte. Lo saqué de [otra respuesta](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/7153/1674) sin verificar que fuera cierto. Lo edito sustituyéndolo por _cohete_.

Comment: @DGaleano: Es mas común que se diga **"cuete" o "cuetes"**, la ortografía formal de "Cohete" solo la he visto aplicada al tipo de pirotecnia que usa la NASA para poner en órbita algun satélite. La acepción homónima de *cuete* con *ebrio* tiene contexto histórico en las fiestas patrias durante el mes de septiembre: se consume tanto alcohol como pólvora, es tradicional el dia de independencia quemar "castillos de cuetes" y el que no llega "cuete" a su casa es porque no honro a nuestros heroes como se debe. https://youtu.be/Jdbu_P1VGC4 *ira, pinshis cuetotes!* (castillos en el min. 9)

Comment: ¿Cuetes?  Creí que era *cohetes*.

Comment: @aparente001 el diccionario de americanismos registra el uso de [_cuete_](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=GYbvfXEWex0AlUBF4at)

Answer (score 4):

La traducción adecuada sería "Fuegos artificiales" tal como se comentaba, sin carácter técnico, es de lenguaje común.

Por otro lado, no se puede usar "petardos" para traducir "Fireworks" porque son dos conceptos diferentes, en el primer caso nos referimos a artefactos 'de mano'  y en el segundo hablamos de artefactos que tienen la capacidad de auto propulsarse, y que en todo caso estallan en el aire produciendo siempre un efecto visual que no se puede atribuir con carácter general a un "petardo".

Answer (score 3):

Es más común emplear la palabra "petardo" que en inglés es `firecracker`, aceptada por la RAE, también usada en Francés y Catalán que se escriben casi igual `pétard`/`petard` creado a partir del del verbo 'petar' ( estallar, ventosear).

En el día a día y en uso familiar, especialmente en San Juan se suele usar petardo. No llamaría fuego artificial a un petardo como las piulas, truenos,etc... que no generan llamas sino explosiones.

A la palabra `fireworks`, si se trata de un evento sí que se suele utilizar fuegos artificiales porque se suelen lanzar varios cohetes que crean explosiones, llamas, chispas de colores.

Answer (score 2):

En México (Ciudad de México, antes D.F.) es más común escuchar `cuetes` para decir `fuegos artificiales`. Aunque en sí la palabra quiere decir un fuego artificial más chiquito la usan como término por todos. Ten cuidado no confundirla con `cuates` que es como amigos o `compadres`.

También hay un dicho que me gusta mucho:

`Tiene cuetes en la cola` - tiene hormigas en el culo - he has ants in his pants. (Se refiere a una persona inquieta)

Comment: También se puede emplear cuando usamos la expresión: `Andas bien cuete (Estas muy ebrio, tomado,pedo)` para los momento que has bebido mucho alcohol. Pero no confundir con los cohetes o juegos artificiales.

Answer (score 1):

Acá en Argentina a los que se ven en el cielo tipo lluvia de luces que explotan se le dice "fuego artificiales".
A los que solamente explotan en el piso se le dice "petardos".
A los que son tipo palo que salen para arriba volando y explotan se le dice "canita voladora". Todo esto también se lo considera "cohete".

> Vamos a tirar cohetes

Comment: ¿Y lo pronuncian cohete?

Comment: A veces cohete, a veces cuete. Depende del contexto y de la educación del que lo dice.

Answer (score 1):

Para la traducción mexicana debo diferir. Fireworks se dice Fuegos Artificiales. No obstante, hay 3 cosas que debes saber:

1) "Cuetes" es una forma incorrecta de decirlo, la cual a pesar de que sí se usa; significa borracho, borrachera o un corte de carne (link http://dle.rae.es/?id=BbKTGhZ.)

2) "Cohete" puede ser empleado y su definición con respecto a la palabra que buscas es: *Fuego de artificio que consta de un canuto resistente cargado de pólvora y adherido al extremo de una varilla ligera. Encendida la mecha que va en la parte inferior del canuto, la reacción que producen los gases expulsados le imprime un rápido movimiento hacia la altura, donde estalla con fuerte estampido* (extraído de http://dle.rae.es/?id=9guhddN). No obstante, no es tan usado en México. 
Cabe notar además, esta definición solo alcanza para un subconjunto de los fuegos artificiales. No todos los fuegos artificiales son cohetes, pero todos los cohetes son fuegos artificiales.

Cualquier duda, la RAE es el sitio oficial donde puedes buscar palabras. Si en ella no está, entonces no existe oficialmente. Espero haya sido de ayuda, ¡Suerte!