# ¿Por qué "tío" designa cariñosamente a una persona próxima?

Tags: etimología, diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, españa, cuba

En España es muy común en el ámbito coloquial llamar *tío* o *tía* a las personas. Tal y como se comentó en [Does using "tío" imply a negative opinion?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/468/1674), no tiene connotación negativa, sino más bien de *colegueo*.

Y algunas acepciones al respecto:

> 6. m. y f. coloq. Persona de quien se pondera algo bueno o malo. *Aquel tío ganó una millonada. ¡Qué tío más pelma! ¡Qué tía más lista!*
> 7. m. y f. coloq. Persona cuyo nombre y condición se ignoran o no se quieren decir. *Nos recibió un tío con poca amabilidad.*
> 8. m. y f. coloq. Persona rústica y grosera.
> 9. m. y f. coloq. U. como apelativo para designar a un amigo o compañero.

Y de hecho acabo de descubrir que el Diccionario de americanismos también lo recoge en Cuba:

> [**tío**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=t%C3%ADo).
>     a. ǁ    mi ~. fórm. *Cu.* tío, para referirse a una persona adulta en tono de confianza.
>   ii. *Cu.* Se usa para referirse a una persona adulta en tono de confianza. pop. ◆ mi tío.

En definitiva, se trata de reinterpretar el apelativo *tío*, que inicialmente sería para el hermano de uno de los padres.

Se podría pensar que en algún momento un tío joven podía ser alguien muy próximo (padre algo mayor con un hermano pequeño cuya diferencia de edad con su sobrino es bastante pequeña y se crea un ambiente de complicidad), pero me gustaría saber si hay algún tipo de origen claro sobre su uso.

Además, ¿por qué se usa solamente en Cuba y España? ¿Se entiende su connotación en países como Colombia, Argentina o México?

Comment: Hasta donde sé, en Colombia tío solo tiene el significado de hermano del padre o la madre. Aunque creo que todos entenderíamos la connotación de cercanía porque la hemos escuchado de españoles (en televisión, al menos).

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @MauricioMartinez Lo entendemos si lo oímos decir con _acento ibérico_  De lo contrario estamos hablando del pariente.

Comment: Releyendo *Las Mil noches y una noche,* veo que se usa con bastante frecuencia la palabra tío, sobre todo, en el mismo sentido que en España, y entonces me pregunto si la traducción del **árabe tío** no será una influencia de ese idioma en ese país...

Answer (score 5):

En **Chile** se usa ampliamente. Yo les digo "tío" y "tía" a varias personas conocidas y cercanas, pero con las que no tengo ningún parentesco. Generalmente son los amigos de mis padres. Los niños les dicen "tío" a todos los adultos de confianza: el conductor del transporte de la escuela, la educadora de párvulos, el vendedor del almacén de la esquina, el vecino, el papá del compañero de la escuela, etcétera.

Me imagino que la respuesta no hay que buscarla en el idioma español sino en la genética. La consanguineidad en cualquier parte del mundo es la causa de las mejores acciones y deseos. Cuando se desea reflejar en el lenguaje el altruismo, los sacrificios, la paz y el regocijo, se recurre frecuentemente al parentesco. Hay montones de ejemplos de parientes ficticios, se me ocurren los siguientes:

> Las *hermanas* de la caridad
>
> La *madre* patria
>
> *Papá* Noel
>
> *Hermanito*, regáleme cien pesos
>
> *Padre* nuestro que estás en el cielo...
>
> Qué pasa *carnal*
>
> Qué onda *bro*
>
> Los *padres* de la iglesia
>
> La *madre* Teresa de Calcuta
>
> El *tío* Sam
>
> *Papaíto* Piernas Largas
>
> La *fraternidad* americana

O sea, para decir cosas buenas puedes recurrir al lenguaje de los parientes sanguíneos.

Puede ser que, igual que en la religión o en la política, a nivel doméstico se quiera expresar que la relación que tenemos con esa otra persona es equivalente a la que tendríamos con un pariente sanguíneo. Y por eso nuestros padres nos enseñan a decirles "tío", aunque no lo sean.

Comment: En Perú también se usa `tío` de esta manera, aunque un poco mas limitada, yo diría que solamente para los amigos de los padres. Sin embargo, el uso no es difundido.

Comment: En España también existe este uso; al menos, existía cuando yo era pequeño. En el pueblo, sobre todo, los niños llamábamos *tío* o *tía* a cualquier persona de la edad de nuestros padres o mayor, fuera familiar o no.

Answer (score 2):

Acá en **La República Argentina**, nosotros usamos el término tío generalmente a el hermano de nuestros padres y madres. O bien Tíos políticos ya sea, el marido no sanguíneo de una tía sanguínea, ¿Y porque no?, en la actualidad algún marido de un tío Sanguíneo (Marido, novio, concubino, etc. a veces).

Pero se da la particularidad de que denominamos tío a adultos de suma confianza, o amigos adultos de la familia que siempre están. Inclusive queda el título de tío a veces a los exmaridos de las tías sanguíneas.

De hecho y esto es un dato aparte, tengo una tía que no supera mucho mi edad. Yo le digo prima porque tía me parece chocante.

Y tengo un sobrino que al tener mi misma edad, nos decimos primos, ya que sino queda chocante.

Comment: Es curioso que les resulte "chocante" usar los parentescos correctos.

Comment: Debe ser algo regional, en mi caso me choca porque yo siempre tuve tías muy grandes a comparación de mi edad. Y en el caso de mi primo, se ofendía si le decíamos sobrino. Creo que él siente que lo menosprecian. No vamos a caer en un análisis psicológico pero... bueno vos me entenderás.

Answer (score 2):

En este hilo de [Wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/t%C3%ADo-un-individuo.637103/) alguien explica

> **Tío/tía** : Individuo. La relación familiar se reinterpreta en sentido figurado para designar a cualquier persona, o bien como apelativo. Se utiliza con gran frecuencia en la actualidad, sobre todo entre los jóvenes, aunque ya se remonta a 1896, en la obra de R. Salillas El delincuente español. El lenguaje, y a 1905, en el Diccionario de argot común español de L. Besses. En este último presenta curiosas acepciones: tío 'hombre despreciable', 'amo, jefe, señor', 'individuo que lleva cartera con valores'; tía 'señora', 'mujer rústica y grosera', 'ramera' : “Y el TÍO ese, va y me acusa, cuando el que había cometido el delito era otro” .© Espasa Calpe, S.A.
>
> Tío o tía , que sacaban de sus casullas [sic] a los “bienhablados”, tienen una gran solera: se utilizaban desde antiguo con el sentido de amigo o amiga, compañero, e incluso tenían valores de reconocimiento y gratitud. Asimiladas por la delincuencia en los ss.XVI y XVII, estas palabras perdieron consideración y *tío* no significó otra cosa que chulo, matón y bravucón. Por su parte, *tía* era tanto como fulana, puta y buscona.

Después de un buen rato buscando por la red, no he conseguido validar esa información ni encontrar su procedencia (no está clara en esa publicación). No entiendo de dónde sale esa afirmación de que el término ya era usado por "la delincuencia en los ss. XVI y XVII". Yo me atrevería a afirmar que no hay un origen claro y documentado al respecto.

En cualquier caso en otros posts o comentarios de ese hilo, los usuarios aportan:

> al parecer se esta poniendo de moda por aquí, iba por la calle, cuando escuché a un chico decirle a otro Tío y se notaban que **eran venezolanos**.
>
> Por acá [por México] decimos también cuñao; en Monterrey dicen primo.

Es de esperar que otros países de habla hispana (o regiones) favorezcan otros términos (como  quillo/a, illo/a, flaco/a en Argentina, etc.) pero entiendan el uso de tío/tía.

Viendo otros hilos como [tío en Argentina](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/t%C3%ADo-en-argentina.2384891/) o [Tío / tía en México y otros países](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/t%C3%ADo-t%C3%ADa-en-m%C3%A9xico-y-otros-pa%C3%ADses.1816040/) parece ser que no se usa como en España en casi ninguno de los países hermanados por el lenguaje.

Answer (score 2):

### parentesco → apelativo

Este fenómeno - que una palabra para un pariente varón se convierte en un apelativo - ha pasado en muchas lenguas, y en castellano con varias otras palabras:

- it: zio
- es: tío, compadre
- es (mx): [mano](https://dle.rae.es/mano#OFAJXYy) <sub>(de *hermano*)</sub>, [carnal](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=carnal) <sub>(de *hermano carnal*)</sub>, [cuate](https://dle.rae.es/?w=cuate) <sub>("mellizo")</sub>
- pt: mano
- en: brother, bro
- fr: [frérot](https://dle.rae.es/mano#OFAJXYy)
- ru: брата́н, браток

Lo mismo pasa con palabras para colegas para razones parecidas:

- es: colega, socio
- it: socio

### Ámbito

Se usa *tío* en [Chile y Cuba](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=t%C3%ADo) en adición de España.

Comment: Relevant: [Nominal address and rapport management in informal interactions among university students in Quito (Ecuador), Santiago (Chile) and Seville (Spain)](https://eprints.bbk.ac.uk/12420/2/12420.pdf) (Table 2.)

Comment: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17233/what-does-cuate-mean

Answer (score 1):

Realmente en Cuba es muy raro que se use tío para referirse a otra persona. Creo que la palabra que más se acerca es "asere". Por ejemplo:

- Venga tío dime la respuesta (España)
- Dale asere dime la respuesta (Cuba)

Comment: ¡Qué bueno que puedas dar tu visión desde Cuba! Hay una [serie de preguntas](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2484/1674) en las que buscamos cómo se dice en distintos países. ¿Querrías darle una ojeada por si puedes aportar tu granito de arena? ¡Gracias!